# MongoDB DigitalOcean using mongodump and mongorestore

Tags: linux, mongodb, scp, mongorestore

I am trying to migrate a mongo database onto a DigitalOcean server. I have dumped the files on my local system(mac). Also, I have tried using SCP file transfer (errored) and tried using mongorestore. If anyone has a good example of how to do this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You might have better luck asking this question on [dba.se] or [sf]. When you do, you should describe in detail what you did and what problems you had, including exact error messages.

Answer (score 1):

with Digital Ocean mongorestore, you will have to use the --uri flag to set the connection string. You will also need to specify the path for the CA certificate file in the connection string. eg.

```
mongorestore --uri="mongodb+srv://**username**:**host**/admin?authSource=admin&replicaSet=db-mongodb-fra1-xxxxxx&tls=true&tlsCAFile=**c:\ca-certificate.crt**" --archive=mobivote.gz --gzip
```

just copy the uri from DO database panel (connection string) with password. Download the CA Certificate and specify the path in the **CAFile** of the connection string.

if your backup is an archive, use --archive to specify the file and --gzip to specify compression.

Answer (score 0):

**mongodump**

```
mongodump --host <HOST_DETAILS> --username <USERNAME> --password <PASSWORD> --authenticationDatabase admin --db <DATABASE>
```

can use `--gzip` in `mongodump` to enable compression

**mongorestore**

```
mongorestore --host <HOST_DETAILS> --username <USERNAME> --password <PASSWORD> --db <database> --authenticationDatabase admin --dir <PATH>
```

include `--gzip` in `mongorestore` to restore from a compressed dump